# How to get only the value from a Rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get the integer value from this query in rails.

```
Inventory.select(:amt_sold).where(item_ID:'GXZ44', store_id:'44555222')
```

On my controller, I am trying to select the amount sold from my inventory and I want to get only the integer value from the `amt_sold` column. When I run that query, I get:

```
< Inventory id: nil, amt_sold: 175.0>
```

How can I just get the 175.0 value as a integer to be able to do arithmetic operations on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
my_int =  Inventory.where(item_ID:'GXZ44', store_id:'44555222').first.amt_sold
```

Comment: I'm a fan of `#pluck` but it's just not elegant in this case: `Inventory.where(item_ID:'GXZ44', store_id:'44555222').pluck.first`. Your solution is better.